# React native application instantly crashes on Testflight instantly due to some type of execution error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am a developer and I create a react native application with expo. I am in the process of publishing it to apple app store for review. I noticed that on my local machine it runs perfectly. When i publish it to Testflight it instantly crashes. I have the backtrace and I went through it but can not figure out exactly what is causing the issue to fix the problem. Can anyone help me figure what the issue is and what is causing the issue by the backtrace. I would really appreciate it.

Here is the backtrace:

```
{"app_name":"Rippe","timestamp":"2023-06-30 12:58:52.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"...","adam_id":"...","build_version":"1","platform":2,"bundleID":"app.rippeapp.com","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.5.1 (20F75)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Rippe","incident_id":"..."}
{
  "uptime" : 65000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad11,6",
  "coalitionID" : 1277,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.5.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20F75"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-06-30 12:58:50.2801 -0700",
  "incident" : "BF86938B-5562-4A8C-B058-1C2DDC77BEDB",
  "pid" : 2981,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-06-30 12:58:50.0089 -0700",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 1560679672274,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 1560686110050,
  "procName" : "Rippe",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/5191B255-ACE4-4921-83C5-49AD676CEF8F\/Rippe.app\/Rippe",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.0","CFBundleVersion":"1","CFBundleIdentifier":"app.rippeapp.com","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6450795147","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"A0B69947-7299-465C-AB19-355D955F323D","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"858167359"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "...",
  "crashReporterKey" : "b3ddb8582d3b8e5e8ba255ff7366f65d3c1291b8",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "...",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "...",
  "codeSigningFlags" : ...,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "ktriageinfo" : "VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage\n",
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":40116,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":99280,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":763356,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1231540,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1233656,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":470020,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":134324,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":428,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":132812,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":958332,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":967008,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":966120,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":8992,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":46388,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":668,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":49316,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":93404,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":3548,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}],
  "faultingThread" : 1,
  "threads" : [{"id":460443,"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3204,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":80724,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":81452,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":540,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4552,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":127500,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply","symbolLocation":548,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":128412,"symbol":"dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":66072,"symbol":"xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync","symbolLocation":240,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":10697388,"symbol":"-[GEOXPCRequest sendSync:error:]","symbolLocation":232,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4833572,"symbol":"_GEOGetAllValuesInStore","symbolLocation":196,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4069504,"symbol":"-[GEOConfigStorageCached resync]","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4068996,"symbol":"-[GEOConfigStorageCached getConfigValueForKey:countryCode:options:source:]","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":75364,"symbol":"___getValue_block_invoke","symbolLocation":552,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":252304,"symbol":"MapKitConfig_GetPropertiesForKey","symbolLocation":2636,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":495192,"symbol":"GEOConfigGetPropertiesForKey","symbolLocation":84,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":495620,"symbol":"_getValue","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":621496,"symbol":"GEOConfigGetInteger","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":261780,"symbol":"__29-[MKMapView _canShowControls]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":22252,"symbol":"_dispatch_once_callout","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":27952,"symbol":"-[MKMapView _canShowControls]","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":27152,"symbol":"-[MKMapView _updateCompassVisibility]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":81904,"symbol":"-[MKMapView _setEdgeInsets:explicit:]","symbolLocation":644,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":79484,"symbol":"-[MKMapView setFrame:]","symbolLocation":220,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":787668,"symbol":"UIViewCommonInitWithFrame","symbolLocation":1896,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":597680,"symbol":"-[UIView initWithFrame:]","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":381520,"symbol":"-[MKMapView _initWithFrame:allowsAntialiasing:]","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2109632,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":2126956,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":781888,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1102288,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":8992,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":75428,"symbol":"_dispatch_main_queue_drain","symbolLocation":928,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":74484,"symbol":"_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":625704,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":501088,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1992,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":521196,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":4956,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":3790568,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":888,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":3789644,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":26012,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":89580,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2220,"imageIndex":11}]},{"triggered":true,"id":460459,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":9279125063},{"value":6103214160},{"value":110},{"value":1280},{"value":1026604933880236379},{"value":1026604931108305243},{"value":512},{"value":11},{"value":11},{"value":2095104},{"value":2043},{"value":3001106507},{"value":328},{"value":6103216128},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":3335},{"value":6103216352},{"value":0},{"value":6103216352},{"value":10781615464},{"value":0},{"value":276},{"value":0},{"value":10755352576}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":9279901976},"cpsr":{"value":1073741824},"fp":{"value":6103214016},"sp":{"value":6103213984},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8729605464,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":9083746008}},"queue":"com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue","frames":[{"imageOffset":30040,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":28952,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":119160,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":72696,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":5188,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":348,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":122532,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":69564,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":69472,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":16064,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":46388,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":668,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":49316,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":93404,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":3548,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460460,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460461,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460462,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460463,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3204,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":80724,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":81452,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":540,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4552,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":495652,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":500304,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":521196,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":270292,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":270012,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":5047292,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":416,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":374084,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":716,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460464,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460465,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460466,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460467,"name":"com.facebook.react.JavaScript","frames":[{"imageOffset":3204,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":80724,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":81452,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":540,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4552,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":495652,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":500304,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":521196,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":836700,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":374084,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":716,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460469,"name":"hades","frames":[{"imageOffset":5464,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":32888,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":77560,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":17},{"imageOffset":1166504,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1165916,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460470,"name":"hermes-chrome-inspector-conn","frames":[{"imageOffset":5464,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":32888,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":77560,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":17},{"imageOffset":1922928,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1630104,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}]},{"id":460471,"name":"hermes-inspector","frames":[{"imageOffset":5464,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":32888,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":77560,"symbol":"std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":17},{"imageOffset":1922928,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1630104,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4364222464,
    "size" : 2998272,
    "uuid" : "c948a991-c5f1-3696-b3e3-9282dcb0609e",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/5191B255-ACE4-4921-83C5-49AD676CEF8F\/Rippe.app\/Rippe",
    "name" : "Rippe"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4374691840,
    "size" : 2998272,
    "uuid" : "dfc2559d-8dda-3d2d-9924-5d5bd62a1218",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/5191B255-ACE4-4921-83C5-49AD676CEF8F\/Rippe.app\/Frameworks\/hermes.framework\/hermes",
    "name" : "hermes"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4373938176,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "695a8449-aae8-38b6-851c-ced0b1176f03",
    "path" : "\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8729575424,
    "size" : 229368,
    "uuid" : "75da6452-934e-3f80-b181-d47074378e83",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7805300736,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "bb347f0e-f21c-3607-82e6-c8d750fdbf8c",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 9280147456,
    "size" : 270336,
    "uuid" : "e999664a-4868-3766-8787-f501fde376e3",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libxpc.dylib",
    "name" : "libxpc.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7777320960,
    "size" : 27979776,
    "uuid" : "29397f67-f971-3720-92ee-6626eba91375",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GeoServices.framework\/GeoServices",
    "name" : "GeoServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7820439552,
    "size" : 3018752,
    "uuid" : "0945ffff-870b-3bd4-a619-1e5dbe1680b9",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/MapKit.framework\/MapKit",
    "name" : "MapKit"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7716855808,
    "size" : 25317376,
    "uuid" : "b3834960-244b-34e4-9ea0-ca4bb44ef0f3",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7682846720,
    "size" : 4096000,
    "uuid" : "4230c122-42e8-383b-beec-ee7b61f8bb61",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8668585984,
    "size" : 36864,
    "uuid" : "e830ad84-d612-3b6b-8de7-ea61a786d132",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8208388096,
    "size" : 547364,
    "uuid" : "6987370a-c385-3135-a27f-6731706bcbd8",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 9279873024,
    "size" : 49140,
    "uuid" : "56698309-210a-3137-97d4-14e4604b1117",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7805591552,
    "size" : 516084,
    "uuid" : "3548f8ee-7a07-3b67-8d69-9c7d42096513",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 9279037440,
    "size" : 98304,
    "uuid" : "b65049d9-dda4-3d03-9e13-0b4795138702",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++abi.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++abi.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7566524416,
    "size" : 278432,
    "uuid" : "085a190c-6214-38ea-accb-428c3e8afa65",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7585583104,
    "size" : 9297920,
    "uuid" : "6e76dc96-11af-3b2e-b71e-215f9cc6e822",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7924224000,
    "size" : 577528,
    "uuid" : "ffa7a30d-b520-3cda-8a7f-63c6cd922df9",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++.1.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++.1.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7565803520,
  "size" : 2951200768,
  "uuid" : "5092a123-2b49-326b-a1dc-4bc5fe375d8b"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=860.8M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=860.8M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=600.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=600.2M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           64K        4 \nCoreAnimation                       16K        1 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           582.6M       45 \nMALLOC guard page                  128K        8 \nSTACK GUARD                        208K       13 \nStack                             7536K       13 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       9360K        8 \n__AUTH                            1639K      172 \n__AUTH_CONST                      22.6M      504 \n__CTF                               824        1 \n__DATA                            6833K      501 \n__DATA_CONST                      26.5M      511 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      5478K      472 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__INFO_FILTER                         8        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       312.4M        4 \n__OBJC_RO                         79.3M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2432K        1 \n__TEXT                           548.4M      523 \ndyld private memory                272K        2 \nmapped file                       37.1M        5 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.6G     2797 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue"
  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "2c2b1e84a5db0fd70fc9f19047364738dfa3310a",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62c74108bcb0435c2153f963",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "6487a5ac8ec1191f379b908b"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000236
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62c73fd17cce0d1b0bcb8a02",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DIALOG_ASSETS" : "645e39c59e69a025b0a37ea1"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000110
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "c28e4ee6-1b08-4f90-8e05-2809e78310a3",
      "experimentId" : "6317d2003d24842ff850182a",
      "deploymentId" : 400000013
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "d3835ae6-d7dd-4c39-8e74-f3fead549120",
      "experimentId" : "631fac54de559130376df80f",
      "deploymentId" : 400000038
    }
  ]
}
}
```